# change a value after 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

How can I change a value in mysql database after 24 hours?
Does a user need to visit the website for the query to run?
For example I have a column named "user-rank" and it's value is "10" ,I want it to be "20" after 24 hours ...

Comment: Could you give more details about exactly why and to what values and when you want this figure to change?

Comment: @AndreasChristodoulou He's given the time he wants it to change (24 hours).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crontab aka CRON is the most flexible solution but you need to have privileges using it in shell or specific control panel as many hosting providers do not like to share privileges to it due security reason.

First create PHP script whit update code, something like this:

```
<?php

//connect to database
//.... 

//prepare MySQL query
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET `user-rank` = `user-rank` + 10";

//execute query and handle errors
//...

//optinal reporting on e-mail
//...

//end
?>
```

Next you need to add entry to crontab by calling "crontab -e" in shell, paste your code like this and save changes:

```
0    0     *     *     *     /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/my_update_script.php > /dev/null
```

This entry will define call to script every day at midnight (server time) and ignore any output from script.

NOTE: You need to specify exact path for php binary which can be different for various OS or user defined profile. Check it with "**which php**" shell command.

--------------- UPDATE ---------------

**Solution without crontab.**

Create one new database table **php_cron** and insert initial record (firs and only one required) with following MySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `php_cron` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `php_cron` (`id`, `last_ts`) VALUES (1,'2012-08-10 00:00:00');
```

Then create new PHP script which will hold all required logic for such task and include it in your master index.php file or other places where it can be loaded every time when user visit your site, for example in some config or similar script. I suppose that you will have at least one visitors per day.

This new script need to do two task, first to query those php_cron table and calculate time difference and if difference is larger than 24h (86400 seconds) then execute code for updating user-rank and save new timestamp into database.

That script may look like this:

```
<?php


    //connect to database
    //.... 

    //get time difference in seconds from last execution
    $sql1 = "SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_ts)) AS tdif FROM php_cron WHERE id=1";
    $res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die("[1] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
    $dif = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1['tdif']);


    if ($dif >= 86400) { //24h

        //following code will run once every 24h

        //update user's page rank
        $sql2 = "UPDATE myTable SET `user-rank` = `user-rank` + 10"; 
        mysql_query($sql2) or die("[2] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

        //update last execution time
        $sql3 = "UPDATE php_cron SET last_ts = NOW() WHERE id=1";
        mysql_query($sql3) or die("[3] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

    }

?>
```

This script is not time accurate as CRON but for sure will be run once per day. That can be corrected with some more php/mysql logic but I thing it will do the job.

Comment: Ok, I will modify my answer with new solution.

Comment: thanks . but if i put this in my header PHP file , for example , it will load for every single visit. the CPU of the server will be under a lot of pressure on high daily visits. am i right ?

Comment: yes, but only for one MySQL query more, so that will not impact on performance so much. On other hand if you have such large traffic, consider option for some other hosting or dedicated server with full range of available options including CRON ;)

Comment: yes you're right.one more thing; for testing this, can i use it (Crontab) on local ? ie. wamp server ?

Comment: As I know, there is no native support for Crontab on Windows so you need to use "Task Scheduler" to simulate that behavior. Solution based on php/mysql can be run almost on any web server including WAMP.

Answer (score 4):

A common solution is to set up a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_job) to periodically run a script to update whatever needs to be updated.

Comment: could you give me a very simple PHP code to do this ? 
i don't have access to shell ! only files in my host.

Answer (score 1):

You could either set up something that runs a query checking the database for a last run time and then you could run the query (All of this when someone visits the site). Or you could set up a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of MySQL, you can use events.

Answer (score 0):

First edit your crontab file (In a terminal)

```
crontab -e
```

Add this line to the file :

```
0    0     *     *     *         php /var/www/myquery.php
```

The first 0 means the minute 0, and the second zero means at 0h. The other stars means the job will be executed every day.

In the file myquery.php you put some php that will connect to your database and that will execute the query you want.

This is a way to do it on linux systems.