# mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Tags: php, mysql

I follow this topic because i have the same problem ( can't use command shell, just edit file host ) -> [change a value after 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891196/change-a-value-after-24-hours)

First run SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `php_cron` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `php_cron` (`id`, `last_ts`) VALUES (1,'2012-08-10 00:00:00');
```

And my code

```
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_ts)) AS tdif FROM php_cron WHERE id=1");
$dif = mysql_fetch_assoc($dif['tdif']);

if ($dif >= 86400) { //24h

    //following code will run once every 24h

    //update user's page rank
    $sql2 = "UPDATE logs_limitbandwidthtoday SET BandwidthToday = 0"; 
    mysql_query($sql2);

    $sql23 = "UPDATE logs_limitlinktoday SET LimitLink = 0"; 
    mysql_query($sql23);

    $sql24 = "UPDATE logs_limitvipbw SET BandwidthToday = 0"; 
    mysql_query($sql24);

    $sql25 = "UPDATE logs_limitviplink SET LimitLink = 0"; 
    mysql_query($sql25);

    $sql26 = "UPDATE account_vip SET ALLTime = ALLTime - 1 WHERE ALLTime > 0"; 
    mysql_query($sql26);

    //update last execution time
    $sql3 = "UPDATE php_cron SET last_ts = NOW() WHERE id=1";
    mysql_query($sql3);

}
```

Error -> PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /.... on line 2

And i am not sure this code still work or not, please give me a answer for this question. Thank you so much !

Comment: $dif = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1);

Comment: Without $res1['tdif'] -> ['tdif'] <- bro ?

Comment: This might work $dif = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1); 

    $dif1 = $dif['tdif']; 
    if ($dif1 >= 86400) {

Comment: So the code will work perfect as like this right @ArjanShrestha ? -> http://notepad.cc/fovoqo35

Comment: That's right it should. @TamVao

Comment: Thank you so much. Because this code from 2012, i don't know does it still work with newest MYSQL and PHP 5.5 until today or not ?

Comment: This code will not work after PHP 7.0 mysqli_ and PDO has replaced mysql_

Comment: Thank you @ArjanShrestha !!

Comment: Ok answered with updated code check it out @TamVao

Answer (score 0):

Ok this should solve the problem

```
$dif = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1); 
$dif1 = $dif['tdif']; 
if ($dif1 >= 86400) {
```

But since mysql_* is outdated and removed from PHP 7.0 updated code should be like this

```
$res1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_ts)) AS tdif FROM php_cron WHERE id=1");
$dif = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1); 
$dif1 = $dif['tdif']; 
if ($dif1 >= 86400) {

    //following code will run once every 24h

    //update user's page rank
    $sql2 = "UPDATE logs_limitbandwidthtoday SET BandwidthToday = 0"; 
    mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

    $sql23 = "UPDATE logs_limitlinktoday SET LimitLink = 0"; 
    mysqli_query($sql23);

    $sql24 = "UPDATE logs_limitvipbw SET BandwidthToday = 0"; 
    mysqli_query($con,$sql24);

    $sql25 = "UPDATE logs_limitviplink SET LimitLink = 0"; 
    mysqli_query($con,$sql25);

    $sql26 = "UPDATE account_vip SET ALLTime = ALLTime - 1 WHERE ALLTime > 0"; 
    mysqli_query($con,$sql26);

    //update last execution time
    $sql3 = "UPDATE php_cron SET last_ts = NOW() WHERE id=1";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql3);

}
```

Where $con is the connection sting you make with the database

```
$server='localhost';//your host name
$user_name='root';//your mysql user name which is root by default
$password='';//your mysql password which is blank by default
$database='db';//your database name

$con=mysqli_connect($server,$user_name,$password,$database);
```